# Unable to use class property from Pod

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem when ill try to use a property of a POD Extension Class.

I forked it and changed some values when ill try it on my device, everything is fine and i can compile it and its running.

But: When ill add the POD to my Project, i am unable to use any properties. For example:

```
public protocol ALCameraImageSaveDelegate {
    func saveImageToTask(image: UIImage)
}

public class ALCameraViewController: UIViewController {

    let cameraView = CameraView()
    let cameraOverlay = CropOverlay()
    let cameraButton = UIButton()

    let closeButton = UIButton()
    let swapButton = UIButton()
    let libraryButton = UIButton()
    let flashButton = UIButton()

    var onCompletion: ALCameraViewCompletion?
    var allowCropping = false
    var delegate: ALCameraImageSaveDelegate?
```

When ill set my delegate (ALCameraImageSaveDelegate) - its fine and i can add it to my class and compile the app. But when ill try to initialize a new controller, and add the delegate:

```
 let cameraViewController = ALCameraViewController(croppingEnabled: false, allowsLibraryAccess: true) { (image) -> Void in
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }

        cameraViewController.delegate = self // not working -> delegate property not found
```

But why it's not found? When ill check in my pod class file, the delegate is here. Why is it not accessible?

Comment: Have you tried to change `var delegate` access level to public? eg. `public var delegate: ALCameraImageSaveDelegate?`

Comment: Yes, already tried, but its not working. When ill set my delegate into my public init function, then it works. But WHY i am unable to set any properties from this controller? Thats strange for me ;)